# Access queried post ID in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to specify/define the currently queried post in `WP_Query` arguments, but having little luck. Not in `the loop`, but while `the query` itself is running. Specifically I want to use the post id to access other metadata.

An example of usage might be:

```
meta_key     => '_an_existing_meta_key',
meta_value   => get_post_meta($current_post_id, '_another_meta_key'),
meta_compare => '!='
```

Where `$current_post_id` is the actual currently queried post ID within the current query being run. Considering that the above example works fine with a hardcoded/specific post ID, it seems like it should work, but I'm having zero luck.

I'm specifically hoping to be able to use a function to define `meta_value`.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has quite a few [global variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables) to choose from which may help. For example, you can use the `global $post` to get first post in the query.

```
global $post;
$my_meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_another_meta_key', true );
```

Or you could reach directly into the $wp_query object posts array and grab the first post:

```
global $wp_query;

if( ! empty( $wp_query->posts ) ) {
    $my_meta_value = get_post_meta( $wp_query->posts[0]->ID, '_another_meta_key', true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Howdy, yeah the $post global is useful, but not quite what I'm looking for. I want to access/define the currently queried post ID WHILE the query is running. Not before/after/in the loop. I think I need to word my question better, putting the issue into words has been a challenge today, which is probably why I can't find a solution :/

Comment: @gcoulson if that's the case PHP may not be able to help you. You might have to use raw SQL.

Comment: yeah, I guess what I'm hoping to find is an argument I can pass that tells the query to use the currently queried post ID, which would exist where `$current_post_id` is.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do sounds more complicated than it needs to be. This might be an XY problem. Maybe edit your question with what specifically you want to accomplish than what you've tried.

Comment: You could be right, I've posted my specific issue over on stackoverflow (wasn't clear about the third party/off-topic rules): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174812/large-woocommerce-query-throws-fatal-memory-errors